# Adverb form of "outlier"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs

I'm looking for an adverb form or synonym of the word "outlier."  An example of usage:

> This datapoint is _____ positive.

I've thought of *disproportionately*, but that word carries additional connotations that may not apply to all use cases.  Thanks for any input you may have.

Comment: Instead of nominalizing *positive*, let the words be their normal parts of speech. This datapoint is a positive outlier.

Comment: I don't think that conveys the same meaning.  Saying that the datapoint is a positive outlier does not necessary imply that the datapoint is an outlier _because_ it is positive, which my original construction would.

Comment: Nouns do usually give rise to adverbs. That said, outlying, the adjective could be made into: outlyingly situated in the middle of the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: No, your original doesn't suggest that, so that is part of the problem. I assumed it was just beyond the highside bound. *Outlier* implies a fully gradable scale. You seem to want to use it for something that has a unique attribute or is separable based on positive/negative. I wouldn't use *outlier* that way.

Comment: @nanogru *the datapoint is an outlier because it is positive* Care to explain what you mean with that? Why would a positive value automatically be an outlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That datapoint is [**atypically**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atypical) positive.
>
> **1** : not typical : IRREGULAR, UNUSUAL · an *atypical* form of a disease · *atypical* weather for this area
>
> the postal service delivered the package with *atypical* speed
> since that's an *atypical* response for an infant, you might want to have her hearing tested

Or, as suggested by that definition, **unusually**.

Answer (score 1):

*Non-negative* with outlier would work. However, speaking as a chemist, *This data point is a positive outlier.* would not be construed as anything other than a non-negative number outside either the control limits or expected range.

Answer (score 1):

*[Outlying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlying)* is the adjective form of [*outlier*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlier), and statistical outliers can also be referred to as *[outlying observations](https://www.google.com/search?q=outlying%20observations)*.

So you could say:

*This datapoint is **positively outlying**.*